# Como ver el valor actual de un useState en React que es de tipo array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

como va? Estoy tratando de entender como funciona el hook de useState y useEffect y me tope con el siguiente problema. Yo tengo un componente sencillo que lo que hace es mostrar los nombres de usuarios que estan guardados en usersOnline. Este es el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El socket no tiene interes en este momento, lo que hace solamente es que cuando alguien se conecta te devuelve el nombre del que se conecta. El problema que tengo es el siguiente, cuando alguien se conecta se dispara el socket.on('connectClient), dentro de este lo que yo quiero hacer es ver si ese client que manda el backend esta en el array usersOnline y pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor de usersOnline siempre es el mismo, no tiene nada dentro. Pero curiosamente en la vista si renderiza los usuarios(en el return que devuelve un div con el item del map de usersOnline). Mi pregunta es: como hago para ver el valor de ese Hook y asi poder ver si el nombre del cliente que viene del backend ya esta insertado en este array. Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Intentaste verlo con `console.log`?

Comment: @Shassain te referis a dentro del socket?

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, siempre devuelve un array vacio el console log, aunque en la vista muestre 2 usuarios

Comment: Volvi a probarlo, si muestra valores en el console log. Pero el find ni siquiera entra porq cuando me paro encima no tiene valores

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes para mostrar código, pega el texto en la pregunta. La parte de la consola del navegador sí tiene sentido mostrarla así, pero el código es más fácil copiarlo para mostrarte soluciones si es texto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que podrias tener un loop infinito con el useEffect como esta dado que la dependencia que le pasas es el usersOnline y adentro del useEffect modificas ese array. Cada vez que se modifica se vuelve a ejecutar la función.

Podrias probar quitando esa dependencia.

```
useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('connectClient', (client) => {
            const isThere = usersOnline.find( x => x == client);
            if (!isThere) {
                setUsersOnline(oldArray => [...oldArray, client]);
            }
        })
        return () => socket.disconnect();
    }, [])
```

Espero haberte ayudado!